# Equivalent of C#'s Array.GetUpperBound() in java

Tags: java, c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to translate C#'s `GetUpperBound()` in java. Let's say we have a 2D array in java:

```
int[][] array = new int[2][3] { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6} };
```

I understand that in C# `array.GetUpperBound(0)` would return `1` (the last index of the first dimension) and `array.GetUpperBound(1)` would return `2` (the last index of the second dimension).

How someone could implement this functionality in java? Is C#'s `array.GetUpperBound(0)` the same as Java's `array[0].length - 1` or `array.length - 1`?

Comment: Exactly what you said. `array.length - 1` = `GetUpperBound()` and `array[0].length - 1` = `array.GetUpperBound(1)`.

Comment: There is no equivalent method in core Java.

Answer (score 1):

`GetUpperBound()` simply returns the index of the last element of the specified dimension in the array. So yes, `array.Length - 1` would provide the same result.